# How to create wrapper script for python so that sys.executable becomes equal to name of this script?

Tags: bash, python, executable

I need to run Python interpreter with custom parameters and custom environment.

Let's say I create a bash script which exports required variables and calls `/usr/bin/python3` with required parameters. When I run Python via this script, `sys.executable` will be still `/usr/bin/python3`.

Can I somehow construct the wrapper script such that `sys.executable` would report the path of the wrapper script? I tried `exec /usr/bin/python3`, but this didn't change the matters.

Comment: That seems to be the definition of `sys.executable`.  Perhaps you want to look in `sys.argv[0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself:

`exec -a "$0" /usr/bin/python3`